# Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given , Angular, Jest

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to use spyOn to spy on functions. But, I get the error. "Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given"

is there anything i should add and improve?

below is the code

```
 public cpfMask(event: any) {
    let newValue = event.target.value;
    const regExp = new RegExp(this.cpfValid);
    this.cpfControl = this.cpfForm.get("cpf");
    const pattern = newValue.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})/, "$1.$2.$3-$4"); 
    event.target.value = pattern;
   
     if (!regExp.test(pattern)) {
       event.target.value = newValue.slice(0, -1);
     }
    }
```

Test unit Jest

```
    describe('TeamsComponent', () => {
      let component: TeamsComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<TeamsComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({      
       declarations: [ TeamsComponent ]
      })
     .compileComponents();
      }));

      beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TeamsComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });

      it('should be created', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      });

       it('should call cpfMask', () => {

       const spy = jest.spyOn(component, 'cpfMask').mockReturnVal(() => 
      {});;
       component.ngOnInit()
       expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

     });

       it('should create', () => {
       const validate = component.cpfMask('111.111.111-11');
       fixture.detectChanges();
       expect(validate).toEqual('437.027.388-94');
     });


      it('should be invalid when string invalid', () => {
       const validate = component.cpfMask('111.111.111-11');
       expect(validate).toEqual({errorCpf: true});
    });


   });
```

The objective is to test the function and validate the cpf document

Comment: please post complete code and not just fragments. There is not enough here to answer the question. What is component?

Comment: hi, add spec test complete @E.Maggini